# Where have all the links to the meta site gone?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, profile-page

Typically, from a user's home page (has tabs for **Profile**, **Activity**, **Settings**) near the top-right corner, underneath all the site buttons, there are two links:

- Meta User
- Network Profile

If you are already on the meta site, there is a link to "Main User".

Today, the link to "Meta User" seems to have gone missing. Pictured below:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It seems to be browser dependent. E.g. Firefox v.52 **ESR** no Meta User link, on Firefox of another branch v. 59, there is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five minutes later, the link is back.

If it wasn't for the screen shots, I would not have believed this myself.

*Move along. There is nothing to see here.*

Comment: *cough*. There's a few odd things going on. I'm tempted to think they're fiddling with the CSS again. Or maybe caching. Its always caching.

Comment: Perhaps [Tim Post lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/195817).